# Python MySQLdb cursor truncating values

Tags: python, mysql, floating-point, decimal

I ran into an interesting problem. I have a MySQL database that contains some doubles with very precise decimal values (for example, 0.00895406607247756, 17 decimal places). This is scientific data so this high level of precision is very important.

I'm using MySQLdb in Python to select data from the database:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM " ...etc...)

for n in range(cursor.rowcount):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row
```

For some reason, when it gets to my very precise decimals, they've been truncated to a maximum of 14 decimal places. (i.e. the previous decimal becomes 0.00895406607248)

Is there any way to get the data from MySQLdb in its original form without truncating?

Comment: you could do `for row in cursor: print(row)`, you know that?

Comment: Thanks. I know that; I'm not really just printing the rows, I'm doing other things with the values. This was just an example of how I'm getting the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What MySQL datatype are you using to store the data? Is it `DECIMAL(18,17)`? `DECIMAL`s have up to [65 digits of precision](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html).

If you set the MySQL data type to use `DECIMAL(...)`, then MySQLdb will convert the data to a Python [decimal.Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) object, which should preserve the precision.

Comment: I'm using DOUBLE. I'll give DECIMAL a shot.